# Ajax Load: opinion request

Tags: ajax, jquery

The business web application that I need to build for our company will use an accordion menu (such as the jQuery UI accordion).

I would like to use link jQuery click events to the accordion menu and load the content dynamically with the ajax .load shorthand. 
Currently I'm dealing with an internal conversation where someone mentions that Ajax is slower than a regular browser request.

Now my question is: is that true, taken into account that:

- The loading time of the accordion-content should be faster (all scripts / css / accordion / header loaded only once at the beginning);
- The Ajax request does not influence the performance of any server actions;

Should I really use a browser request - and will it really be faster?

It seems very un-intuitive, using an accordion to use it as a static element that is just displayed on every page refresh.

I built a prototype before, using Ajax Load to load div containers with html and javascript, and it loaded as fast as a normal browser request would.

Comment: Each AJAX load request would typically be smaller than an entire page request, which usually also means faster as there's less to download from the server each time (as long as you really are just fetching the contents you need, not an entire page and grabbing parts of it inside the `load()`). There's also *perceived* performance to consider; in single-page/AJAX applications, the container page will render first, quickly followed by the dynamic content. The more the user sees sooner the happier they are.

Comment: This is my doubt: "not an entire page and grabbing parts of it inside the load()"

What happens if I fetch a PHP page that may use plugins and jquery scripts? In the prototype I built, I didn't notice any performance loss. 
Since the both the HTML and scripts are loaded into the DOM, they are also replaced each time the container is loaded with new content (so the DOM doesn't grow in this sense).

Comment: For starters, "a browser request" == GET, which is what `.load()` does behind the scenes with a `new XMLHttpRequest()`. The difference is that your ajax requests can run in paralell with the "main flow" of the page, instead of a single synchronized load. I don't see any downsides with it. As far as scripts on the dynamically loaded pages go: Even if you add them in a script tag, they will still be cached (as a part of the HTML page that you're fetching), assuming you dont set `cache: false` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Disabling the cache where I don't need it seems in place.

Answer (score 1):

As for an answer, an ajax request is indeed smaller than a regular request for a page.

You have a few options where you could - pre-fetch the data, store this in an array or object and load it onclick of the slider,

or simply use ajax, this however will create another request which, if you have alot of users could potentially slow down your website.

pre-loading data into your html in hidden divs, or via a js.php directly into an array / object would be the most efficient way depending on the size of the contents.

Do know that ajax loaded content is not indexed by search engines and will be less SEO friendly.

Comment: Thank you, that is not necessary as we are dealing with a business application. I'm not sure if preloading data is a good idea, as it will increase the DOM with the multiple pages that I want to load dynamically. Are you saying that Ajax load loses performance against regular browser requests in case of many users?

Comment: Yes, since your server will have to handle more requests, hence the preloading. One of the options I mentioned was to inject it into a js.php file which would be included in the dynamic pages, this would be valid JS when rendered (PHP can render anything like HTML / CSS / JS) this would have the advantage of not clogging the DOM and still providing a fast way of retrieving the data.

Comment: @KimGysen An option would be to make one ajax request -> save the data in `$.cache`, and fetch whatever you need when the users click the menu. This will increaste the number of requests to 2 per user, but will make the page load faster.

Comment: Good suggestion @Johan however, if there are alot of people working with that app, it might stress the server (depending on capabilities)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: Are you suggesting that the Ajax request will cause a lot more performance loss against a regular browser request? In the end: they are both page loads, so wouldn't both ways (ajax vs browser request) stress the server?

Comment: @Johan Thanks, I will check out that option. My plan was actually to load the js scripts from the PHP file that is being loaded and disable the cache.

Comment: @Johan it would not matter alot except for the fact that the AJAX will be executed on every click, while on the page, aka more requests will happen if the user clicks multiple slides.